# What is the status of ranges in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, iterator, range

Sometimes I get tired of all this `my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end()` noise. Last year at boostcon, Andrei Alexandrescu's keynote speech was titled [Iterators Must Go](http://www.boostcon.com/site-media/var/sphene/sphwiki/attachment/2009/05/08/iterators-must-go.pdf) ([video](http://www.mefeedia.com/watch/21421420))

Is there any progress on introducing ranges into C++, so I can finally say `std::sort(my_vector)`?

Comment: Is there some march on to make C++ look more like Python?

Comment: @Mike: One can hope.

Comment: I've seen range-based interfaces of algorithms somewhere while reading about C++0X but can't remember where. So I'd like to know the answer now.

Comment: I'm watching that video now.  It's annoying how people keep interrupting him with questions.  I wish he would hold off all questions till the end.

Comment: I too am hoping for ranges, one day... however I find the title of Alexandrescu's presentation a little too carried away. What should algorithm like `lower_bound` return if not an iterator ?

Comment: @Mat: We could deprecate `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` in favor of `equal_range` ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow: ah but that's not the same, especially when the equal range would be long, then `lower_bound` is faster to compute, and that is all that is needed to know where to insert if you don't care about order.

Comment: @Mat: Hm, maybe `new_lower_bound(b, e)` could return `range(old_lower_bound(b, e), e)` then?

Comment: Ranges would be better than iterators. Ranges are basically iterators done a bit better. However, we certainly don't want BOTH, I am sure.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone not quite, but there is a definite march to make C++ better, more accessible, more expressive and easier to use. Since Python has many of the same goals, it's not surprising that they end up with some similarities... :)

Comment: I don't see why we wouldn't want both. If I call `std::find`, I expect the result to be a pointer to a specific element in a range -- an iterator. Anything else is silly. If I want to convert that into a range, that's great, and there should certainly be easy ways to do that, but IMO they express different things, and while one can emulate the other, I'd prefer to have both: use ranges for algorithms which return ranges of elements, and iterators for algorithms which return specific positions in a range.

Comment: Related: [Status of ranges for C++17/C++2x?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22330968/341970)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Range in C++ still has an insufficient experience.
As current experimental implementation, there are Boost.Range 2.0 and Oven Range Library.

Comment: And every standard algorithm is wrapped in the boost lib, so at least `boost::sort(my_vector)` (if not `std::sort`) is *present*, not future.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no progress has been made toward that end.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template< class Container >
void sort( Container& c ) { sort( c.begin(), c.end() ); }

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int const           data[]  = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 4};
    vector<int>         v( data, data + sizeof( data )/sizeof( *data ) );

    sort( v );
    copy( v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>( cout, " " ) );
}
```

Of course, replace member function calls `begin` and `end` with calls of `startOf` and `endOf` (your versions), at least until C++0x...

Comment: boost::begin and boost::end work until you have support for std::begin and std::end.

Comment: That don't answer the question, doesn't it?

Comment: @Klaim: it answers one of the questions, the OP's expressed wish to be able to "finally say `std::sort(my_vector)`". Noah answered the main question. Anyway, don't spoil a good answer by insisting there has to be a question. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: This answer is more interesting than a "yes/no" answer. So it's worth an upvote. kthx.

Comment: I don't agree because it's an obvious answer. The question is more about making this standard than providing a solution.