# Status of ranges for C++1z?

Tags: c++, c++11, range, standards, c++17

There is a study group on ranges in the C++ committee:

[image: http://isocpp.org/files/img/wg21-structure.png]

but I have not followed the history of this study group and I am not sure of what kind of delivery is expected for C++1z (furthermore I do not use boost.range so I do not have a clear view of existing practices). Will we have:

1. ranges as a pair of first/last iterators?
2. union and other set operations on ranges(for example `[v.begin()+5, v.begin()+7[ U [v.begin()+10, v.begin()+15[ U [v.begin()+21, v.begin()+42[`), namely: union, intersection, disjoint union, complement?
3. iterator filters (in order to execute a for_each where a condition is satisfied)?
4. other things?

Comment: Eric Niebler will be posting (or has already?) his [`Iterable` et al.](http://ericniebler.com/2014/02/16/delimited-ranges/) range implementation and trying to get that standardized, so there's lots of hope there.

Comment: +1 for a pretty graph!  As an uneducated guess: ranges will first show up as a library construct before they become a syntactic element (if they every become a syntactic element).  Do we need a C++2x tag? ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculation. It belongs on the [std-proposals](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals) forum.

Comment: it is not about speculation. There are standard documents/drafts that go into what / why / how of the proposal. There are industry leading people that talk about this kind of things (e.g. Herb Sutter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eric Niebler initiated discussion of his `Iterable` work (four-part blog posting: [Part 1](http://ericniebler.com/2014/02/16/delimited-ranges/), [Part 2](http://ericniebler.com/2014/02/18/infinite-ranges/), [Part 3](http://ericniebler.com/2014/02/21/introducing-iterables/), [Part 4](http://ericniebler.com/2014/02/27/ranges-infinity-and-beyond/)) on the [SG9 mailing list](http://www.open-std.org/mailman/listinfo/ranges) [on Feb 27](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ranges/2014-February/000349.html). There's been quite a bit of back and forth since then, especially considering that the list had been dead for about a year.

As near as I can tell as an outsider, the SG is in the "arguing about what they're trying to do" phase which is quite far from the "developing wording for a Standard/Technical Specification" phase. This is, however, a substantial move forward from the "dormant" phase. The meeting minutes from the last few committee meetings are illuminating:

- [2013-05-03 (Bristol)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3622.pdf):

  > Marshall Clow [the study group chair] reports group is currently suffering from an excess of vision. There are no papers. SG9 is trying to constrain scope. Nothing expected to go into C++14
- [2013-10-16 (Chicago)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3768.pdf):

  > Clow    reports no  activity    in  past    few months. One paper   to  discuss [I believe [N3752 "Index Based Ranges"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3752.pdf)].    Will    have    evening session.
- [2014-03-03 (Issaquah)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3901.pdf):

  > Clow reports no  papers  and no  meeting.    [Stephan] Lavavej   reports a   ranged  for paper   in  EWG that    the range   people  may care    about [I believe referring to [N3853 "Range-Based For-Loops: The Next Generation"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm)]. Dawes   asks    if  work    is  stalled.    Clow    says    his work    is  stalled and he  has not seen    work    others  are doing.  [Jeffrey] Yasskin   says    that    he  is  unsure  of  where   the papers  are going   which   may be  stalling    SG9 consideration   of  papers.

It hasn't exactly been going like gangbusters, and there is no set deliverable goal AFAIK.