# How to Properly Implement Ranges in a New Container

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, range, containers

I recently found this [slide show](http://www.slideshare.net/rawwell/iteratorsmustgo) by Andrei Alexandrescu discussing why Ranges are a better adaptation for STL containers than iterators.

Is there a guide or standard for how to define Ranges for New Containers in C++, the same way there are many guides for how to define iterators for containers in C++?  If not, can anyone explain here the proper procedure for defining a Range for a Container Class?

Comment: Very Related: [What is the status of ranges in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220247/what-is-the-status-of-ranges-in-c)

Comment: You might be interested in [Status of ranges for C++17/C++2x?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22330968/341970)